# Import an S3 method from a package that does not define the generic function

Tags: r, namespaces, package

How can I import an S3 method from an `R` package without *depending* on the package when the generic function of the method is not defined in that package?

More specifically, my `btergm` package (on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=btergm) and [GitHub](https://github.com/leifeld/btergm)) imports several functions from the `ergm` package. It also uses the `formula` method (defined in `ergm`) of the `simulate` generic function (defined in the `methods` package). I would like to import this method from `ergm`. How do I do that?

I have read elsewhere that I could just add a dependency to the `ergm` package. But I do not want to move `ergm` from `Imports:` to `Depends:` in the description because the `btergm` package defines its own `gof` function, while a function with that name is also present in the `ergm` package. This would cause a warning that my package overwrites the `gof` function after loading `ergm`, and CRAN does not like warnings.

It kind of works without the import at the moment. However, the `lme4` package also defines a `formula` method for the `simulate` generic function. If somebody loads `lme4` after loading `ergm`, the wrong method is picked by my code. Hence the need for a proper import.

The current setup in the description file of the `btergm` package:

```
Imports: stats4, utils, methods, graphics, network (>= 1.13.0), sna (>= 2.3.2), ergm (>= 3.10.0), parallel, Matrix (>= 1.2.2), boot (>= 1.3.17), coda (>= 0.18.1), stats, ROCR (>= 1.0.7), speedglm (>= 0.3.1), igraph (>= 0.7.1), RSiena (>= 1.0.12.232), statnet.common (>= 4.2.0)
Suggests: 
    fastglm (>= 0.0.1),
    testthat
Depends: R (>= 3.5), xergm.common (>= 1.7.7), ggplot2 (>= 2.0.0)
```

And the relevant part from the namespace file:

```
import("methods")
...
importFrom("ergm", "ergmMPLE")
importFrom("ergm", "control.simulate.formula")
importFrom("ergm", "remove.offset.formula")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm.getnetwork")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm.getmodel")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm.Cprepare")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm.design")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm.pl")
importFrom("ergm", "control.ergm")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm.getglobalstats")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm.geodistdist")
importFrom("ergm", "ergm")
importFrom("ergm", "mcmc.diagnostics")
```

In the `ergm` package, the namespace export looks as follows:

```
S3method(simulate,formula)
```

How do I import this now? Is it `importFrom("ergm", "simulate")` or `importFrom("ergm", "simulate.formula")` or `importFrom("ergm", "formula-method")` or something completely different? The [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports) section on specifying imports does not say anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

The `simulate` generic is actually defined in `stats`, not `methods`.  If you want to make sure the `simulate.formula` method from `ergm` is found, you need to make sure that the `ergm` package is loaded; your other imports from that package will ensure that.

However, if `lme4` is loaded later, then its `simulate.formula` method will take precedence, and you'll get a message like

```
> library(lme4)
Loading required package: Matrix
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'lme4':
  method           from
  simulate.formula ergm
```

If `lme4` was loaded first, you'll presumably get a warning when `ergm` overwrites its `simulate.formula` method, and probably something in `lme4` will break.

There's not a lot you can do to prevent this:  it's a weakness of the S3 system.

The ideal solution is for the maintainers of `stats` (R Core), `ergm` (Pavel N. Krivitsky) and `lme4` (Ben Bolker) to get together and decide on what `simulate.formula` should do, probably putting it in `stats`, and one or both of the other packages would then rename their method.  That's not likely to be quick.

Another possibility is for you to get the maintainer of `ergm` to export the method, so you can call `ergm::simulate.formula` explicitly.

For a workaround, you might be able to define your own function using

```
simulate.formula <- ergm:::simulate.formula
```

and not export it.  Because it looks like a method defined in your own namespace, I think it will have priority over the registered methods, and your code should work.  However, you will get a check warning about using `:::`; you might be able to get away with this by explaining the need for it in your submission message.